# How to avoid a global variable on function pointer in C

Tags: c, struct

I'm using a global variable `z` as a counter. Is there a way to use MyStruct len as my counter instead? I would prefer not to use a global variable.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glib.h>

typedef struct st { 
    char *key;
    char *str;
    int len;
} MyStruct;

int z = 0;
static void hash2struct (gpointer key, gpointer value, gpointer data) {
    MyStruct **s = data; 
    gchar *k = (gchar *) key;
    gchar *h = (gchar *) value;
    s[z]->key = strdup(k);
    s[z]->str =strdup(h);
    z++;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i;

    GHashTable *hash = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash, g_str_equal);

    g_hash_table_insert(hash, "Virginia", "Richmond");
    g_hash_table_insert(hash, "Texas", "Austin");
    g_hash_table_insert(hash, "Ohio", "Columbus");

    MyStruct **s = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct) * 3);
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        s[i] = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct)); 
    }
    g_hash_table_foreach(hash, hash2struct, s); 

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf("%s %s\n", s[i]->str, s[i]->key);

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        free(s[i]->str);
        free(s[i]->key);
        free(s[i]);
    }
    free(s);
    g_hash_table_destroy(hash);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a comment, but if you are using GLib then you should really make use of GLib's memory allocation functions etc and not mix them with non-GLib functions. (For example, use `g_new(MyStruct, 3)` instead of `malloc(sizeof(MyStruct) * 3)`)

Comment: @codebeard: thanks for the suggestion. Aside from consistency, do you know if there are technical differences between g_new and malloc?

Comment: yes, there are technical differences. Please read the GLib documentation it's quite well-written.

Comment: Also, `malloc(sizeof(MyStruct) * 3)` is not what you want. That returns a pointer to memory for three MyStruct objects, but you are assigning it to `s` which is a *pointer to* a pointer to a MyStruct object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are presumably envisioning `z` as keeping track of the number of cells used in the allocated array. If you tried to stick the value into the individual `MyStruct`s you would risk multiple different values.

Instead consider that you could package up the array and it's counter (in effect building a dynamic array type):

```
struct {
   int length;
   MyStruct *ary;
} MyStructDArray;
```

They you keep one instance of this thing and pass *that* to your `hash2struct` routine.